# Using vc140 Boost for Visual Studio 17

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I am currently linking boost to my current project. The libs I have been provided (I cannot ask to change them) are vc140 [They are named something like : boost_thread-vc140-mt-x64-1_67.lib]. Now, when I try to build my code, I get an error.

Error log:

```
LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.lib'
```

The same can be removed using the vc141 variants (I tried using the same after downloading it once). Reading through some materials, I find that vc140 is for Studio 15 while vc141 is for Studio 17].

This [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2017) seems to suggest vc140 will work with Studio 17. Any suggestions about what might be going wrong?

P.S. I've tried using add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB) and Boost::disable_autolinking

P.P.S My cmake is succeeding. The problem crops up during compilation. The Linker > Command Line display seems to suggest that the vc140 library is being linked successfully.

message(${Boost_LIBRARIES}) prints:

```
optimized
[path-to-boost]/tools/lib/boost_thread-vc140-mt-x64-1_67.libdebug
[path-to-boost]/tools/lib/boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_67.liboptimized
[path-to-boost]/tools/lib/boost_system-vc140-mt-x64-1_67.libdebug
[path-to-boost]/tools/lib/boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_67.liboptimized
[path-to-boost]/tools/lib/boost_date_time-vc140-mt-x64-1_67.libdebug
[path-to-boost]/tools/lib/boost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_67.liboptimized
[path-to-boost]/tools/lib/boost_chrono-vc140-mt-x64-1_67.libdebug
[path-to-boost]/tools/lib/boost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_67.liboptimized
[path-to-boost]/tools/lib/boost_atomic-vc140-mt-x64-1_67.libdebug
[path-to-boost]/tools/lib/boost_atomic-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib
```

Script snippet:

```
# Boost headers dependency (and boost_system calls generated by inline
# functions)
if (WIN32)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
    find_package(Boost 1.67 REQUIRED
        COMPONENTS thread system date_time chrono)
else ()
    find_package(Boost 1.67 REQUIRED
        COMPONENTS thread system)
endif ()

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${MAIN_TARGET} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

# we know how to link against Boost ourselves, thank you...
add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)
```

Comment: The error text suggests that you did not use `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`

Comment: Show the linker line from the MSVC property tab. Also show the relevant parts of the cmake script. What is the value of `${Boost_LIBRARIES}`?

Comment: @VTT As defined, BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB  has been used. I double checked the same in the Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Command Line. The same contains /D "BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB".

Comment: @ixSci As requested, I've added the script snippet and value of ${Boost_LIBRARIES}.

Comment: You say you can't _ask_ for vc141 libs. But why bother? Build them yourself.

Comment: It seems your VS project settings is set for toolset v141, change it to v140 so that it can work with your boost binaries. If the prefix libboost conflicts, try renaming the lib filename to prefix boost manually.

Comment: As stated, I already did. But the batch of libs is being used bundled with our software and caters to multiple other services. Asking to switch to vc141 means asking everyone else to switch as well. My boss is not okay with it.

Comment: Select Project configuration, and under Configuration Properties/General , choose Platform Toolset V140. V140 is downward compatible with VS 2017

Comment: @seccpur That changes the code to compile in VS2015. We give the code to our clients (partially), so I cannot propose them to build in VS2015.

Comment: You can build v140 toolset projects in VS 2017 without any problem.

Comment: Tried it. The build failed with the same error. I'm starting to wonder if its caused by some other 3rd party dependency library (Is that even possible?).